# Proving the solution to linear programming problem is always the boundaries

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Show that the solution $\mathbf{y}$ to the following linear problem:

$$\min c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + \cdot \cdot \cdot + c_nx_n$$
$$\text{subject to} \ \ a_i\leq x_i\leq b_i \ \ \ \ i = 1,2,....n$$

is:

$$
\mathbf{y}_i = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            a_i & \quad c_i > 0 \\
            b_i & \quad c_i < 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Any idea or suggestion on how to go about this probelm?

Comment: Suppose you have a solution that does not satisfy the conditions. Show that you can find a smaller cost value which contradicts being a solution in the first place.

Comment: I think it's straightforward. You really need to prove that?

Comment: @copper.hat I see. A proof by contradiction might work. What do you mean by "cost value"?

Comment: @NN2 How is that comment possibly helpful?

Comment: @Morcus The cost is the objective $c_1 x_1+\cdots$.

Comment: Note that there may be infinitely many optimal solutions- it's not appropriate to refer to "the" optimal solution.  You should be trying to show that the solution you've described is "an" optimal solution.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Assuming $c_i \not= 0$, there is only one optimal solution.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the constraints as $x_i \ge a_i$ and $-x_i \ge -b_i$, construct the dual linear program with dual variables $\alpha_i \ge 0$ and $\beta_i \ge 0$, and note that the dual solution $\alpha^*_i = \max\{c_i,0\}$ and $\beta^*_i = \max\{-c_i,0\}$ is dual feasible and has the same objective value as your proposed primal feasible solution.

If you multiply both sides of $x_i \ge a_i$ by $\alpha^*_i$ and both sides of $-x_i \ge -b_i$ by $\beta^*_i$ and then add these up, you obtain
$$\sum_i (\alpha^*_i - \beta^*_i) x_i \ge \sum_i (\alpha^*_i a_i - \beta^*_i b_i). \tag1$$
By the choice of $\alpha^*_i$ and $\beta^*_i$, we have $\alpha^*_i - \beta^*_i = c_i$, and $(1)$ becomes
$$\sum_i c_i x_i \ge \sum_{i:c_i > 0} c_i a_i + \sum_{i:c_i < 0} c_i b_i,$$
and this lower bound on the objective function certifies the optimality of your proposed solution $\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: Thank you. I am still not understanding the language of "dual" and "primal". Would you mind explaining the answer in a simpler language, if possible?

Comment: [Duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Duality) is fundamental to linear programming.  For the present question, just multiply both sides of $x_i \ge a_i$ by $\alpha_i^*$ and both sides of $-x_i \ge -a_i$ by $-\beta_i^*$, and add these up to derive a lower bound on the objective of the original problem.

Comment: Sorry bear with me :). Doing so will give us $x_i \geq \dfrac{a_i\ \alpha_i^* - b_i \beta_i^*}{ \alpha_i^*-\beta_i^*}$. I don't understand for what exactly this constitutes a lower bound in the original probelm.

Comment: Sorry, I had a couple of typos in my comment.  I have updated my answer with the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see it now. Just to make sure we have everything in the post, is the dual program for this problem $\max c^Tx$ s.t. $a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i$?

Comment: Glad to help.  No, the dual program is maximization but has variables $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$.